# Cannot backup postgres with pg_dump on os x 10.9 due to version mismatch

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgres.app

I am getting

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.0; pg_dump version: 9.1.4
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

In my .bash_profile I have

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

In my .profile I have

```
:5432:*:postgres:root
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"
```

How do I force postgres to make a simple backup?

Comment: Its seems that you have more than one of `pg_dump` version, can you please try to modify in your `.bash_profile` file: `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH` to `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` and try again ? (you have to terminate your terminal console before)

Comment: What does ```which pg_dump``` output?

Comment: which pg_dump gives export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin which seems to be correct, so how to get it pointing to the right pg_dump.

Comment: I downloaded a new version of postgres 9.3.2 and now it is working. Not sure why, but better than 9.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a new version of postgres 9.3.2 and now it is working. Not sure why, but better than 9.3.0.